# How to put curly braces on new line in vscode for c++?

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-code

I have this option in settings:

```
Clang_format_fallback Style : Visual studio
Clang_format_style : file
```

But when I write

```
int main(){
}
```

braces are on the same line, but I want to put them on the new line like this:

```
int main()
{
}
```

How to achieve that?

edit: settings like

"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,

do not help for c++ (only for js)

EDIT2: .clang-format:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  #AfterExternBlock: false # Unknown to clang-format-5.0
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false

BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
```

which of these settings are responsible for my issue?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: I fear I would not find this specific question. But I have looked on other SO question, And they suggest to change the clang format settings to this: `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"` which did not help

Comment: If your clang-format is set to file, [what's in your `.clang-format` file](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)?

Comment: If you examine all the options, and one of them is described as the one you need, that would answer your specific question, no?

Comment: Google's style attaches opening braces, so naturally it wouldn't help. You simply need to edit your .clang-format to how you want your code formatted. I know this setting is in there, I'm just too lazy to look it up. Hence, a comment.

Comment: @chris I have no idea. I do not even know, where that file find. Asteroids it would, I do not know how examine all options, cannot see it. sweenish, I am sorry I am not going to read full compiler documentation just because I want simple brace on new line, it does not seem approriate the effort

Comment: @chris anyway, see edit2